# How to use values from combo box to calculate in c#

Tags: c#, combobox

I am doing a clothing shop program and my code is this.

```
cbmale.Items.Add(new Data { Name = "Male Shirt", Value = "10.0f" });
cbmale.Items.Add(new Data { Name = "Male Jeans", Value = "20.0f" });
cbmale.Items.Add(new Data { Name = "Male Pants", Value = "20.0f" });
cbmale.Items.Add(new Data { Name = "Male Socks", Value = "20.0f" });
cbmale.Items.Add(new Data { Name = "Male Hoodie", Value = "20.0f" });
cbmale.DisplayMember = "Name";
cbmale.ValueMember = "Value";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int quantity = (int)nudmale.Value;
    bool isRBchecked = rbsmallmale.Checked || rbmediummale.Checked || rblargemale.Checked;
    if (isRBchecked == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a size of the selected male item");
        totalpricemale = 0.0f;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbmale.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Item is Selected");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Item Selected is:" + cbmale.Text);
    }

    totalpricemale = totalpricemale + quantity * 
    lblmale.Text = totalpricemale.ToString("C");
}
```

So how do i use the values that i have inserted to calculate the total price of the items selected?
Right now my formula for calculating is this
totalpricemale = totalpricemale + quantity
So how do i include the value in this formula?

Comment: Pretty sure it would be total * quantity, #Facepalm.

Comment: But how do i use the values that i have put such as male jeans 20$?

Comment: Well firstly I must ask why you chose to use a combo box?

Comment: Its a project and i am required to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to actually pull the values you have stored in the combo box?

```
cbmale.SelectedItem
```

Will return the Data object stored in the Combobox that is currently selected.

If what you are trying to do is get the currently selected item in the combobox, then multiply its price by the quantity stored in `nudmale.Value` then you should do this:

```
totalpricemale = totalpricemale + (quantity * cbmale.SelectedItem.Value);
```

Edit: I don't know what Data object this is, I'm not sure if .Value will get you what you are looking for, but you should get the point.

Comment: Thanks but i got an error of does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'item' when i tried using cbmale.Items.Item(cbmale.SelectedIndex)

Comment: Sorry, instead of cbmale.Items.Item it should be cbmale.Items[index], in C# the list objects are handled like arrays.

Comment: Could you post your code? I have modified my original post to be a bit less general.

Comment: I have refined my post again, now that i finally understand exactly what you are attempting to do. In the future you might want to post as much code as necessary that is relevant to your question, that way we can make sense of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh ok thanks but when i tried totalpricemale = totalpricemale + (quantity * cbmale.SelectedItem.Value); it shows an error of 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting
a first argument of type ' object could be found (are you missing a using directive or and
assemly reference?

Comment: No, it's like i said, i have no idea where you are getting this Data object from, as far as i can tell it must be some structure that you have created. In order to use that Data object, you need to find the implementation and figure out how to access the Value member. It also doesn't help that you are storing the value as a string, not an actual number. You would need to convert this string into a number if you are going to continue using this implementation.